# Android: Different app behaviour observed while removing App from the Recent Apps when app is in Idle state and service is running

Tags: android, android-service

Different app behavior observed while removing App from the Recent Apps when app is in Idle state and service is running.

When I remove the app from Recent Apps, some times only app gets killed; but sometimes, even service stops. I have to force stop the app and restart to run my services.

Any suggestions to improve/make it consistent?

Comment: Does your service call `startForeground()`?

Comment: yes. it calls startForeground()

Comment: can I hide both service and app from recent apps? can this be a better option?